# iOS share pdf with webView

Tags: html, ios, swift, pdf

I have a problem with `webView`. I completely load the content of `webView`:

```
func openUrl(fileURL: URL, htmlString: String) {
    webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: fileURL)
}
```

but then I want to share content.

When I tried:

```
    let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [webView.request?.url], applicationActivities: nil)
    let popover = activityController.popoverPresentationController
    popover?.sourceView = self.view
    popover?.barButtonItem = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
    present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It didn't work, there wasn't image what i load from function `loadHTMLString`

How can i share it?
Does anybody know how this problem solve?